# GraniteDS 3.0 tutorial project maven install error

Tags: java, apache-flex, maven, air, graniteds

I am trying to install GraniteDS sample project using maven 3.1.1 under windows 7 64 bit.
I was following the tutorial published on :
https://github.com/graniteds-tutorials/graniteds-tutorial-data

Reproduced steps:

1. Installed maven 3.1.1 (extracted binary zip and create M2_HOME, M2
   variables and added  "%M2_HOME%\bin" to PATH)
2. Installed git 1.8.5.2 for windows
3. Run git shell, and execute:

   `cd c:\dev\ws_flex\fb4.7`

   `git clone http://github.com/graniteds-tutorials/graniteds-tutorial-data.git`

   `cd graniteds-tutorial-data`

   `mvn clean install asciidoctor:process-asciidoc -Dserver=spring -Dclient=air`

And i'm geting Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tutorial-data-server-model: Could not
resolve dependencies for project org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-server-mo
del:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.granite
ds:granite-server:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT, org.graniteds:granite-server-hibernate4:ja
r:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT, org.graniteds:granite-server-eclipselink:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT, o
rg.graniteds:granite-server-openjpa:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact
org.graniteds:granite-server:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
n project tutorial-data-server-model: Could not resolve dependencies for project
 org.graniteds.tutorials:tutorial-data-server-model:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The follow
ing artifacts could not be resolved: org.graniteds:granite-server:jar:3.0.0.SNAP
SHOT, org.graniteds:granite-server-hibernate4:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT, org.graniteds:
granite-server-eclipselink:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT, org.graniteds:granite-server-open
jpa:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.graniteds:granite-server:jar
:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT
and more...
```

and a few debug warnings

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.graniteds:granite-server:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT/mave
n-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\devel\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.graniteds:granite-server:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT/mave
n-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\devel\.m2\repository)
[WARNING] The POM for org.graniteds:granite-server:jar:3.0.0.SNAPSHOT is missing
, no dependency information available
```

and more...

I am absolutely newbie in maven. I will be glad of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Just replaced 3.0.0.SNAPSHOT to 3.0.0.GA in server-model/pom.xml (only org.graniteds.* artifacts).
See maven repository:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graniteds

Comment: Hmm there was indeed a typo in the pom. Fixed now.